# How to replace a cell with a new value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a cell with a number that I'd like to be continuously modified after subtraction, say it says 100 and is subtracted by a randomized value, I'd like the cell to replace itself with the new value

Comment: possible only with script

Comment: Try formula in cell =100-RANDBETWEEN(1,100).  Everytime something changes on the sheet the cell value will change